# Customize Search interface - icon and text

Tags: android, search, customization

Our Android app has a persistent Search bar but we would like to customize the icon (magnifying glass) and the default "Search" text. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your search icon from the menu xml file which is written in the res/menu directory

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"/>

</menu>
```